# Add Godaddy SSL to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I have Godaddy Domain Pointed to AWS EC2 instance and also I have Purchased SSL from GoDaddy. I need to enable HTTPS for my side now. My I have Ubuntu instance with Apache installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate csr file first on ec2, after validation, download the certificates. Afterwards enable ssl on apache2 in the config file. [You can follow this tutorial on digital ocean for detailed explantaion](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority)

Answer (score 0):

1. Please generate your CSR first, you can ask support team to generate it for you
2. Enroll your CSR on Godaddy SSL portal
3. Then, you can install your .cer on the server.

If you are not too sure, you can ask help from support team